# Перенос значений в массиве

Tags: python-3.x

> Есть массив значений разбитый на 3 подмассива. Необходимо что бы крайние массивы array[0] и array[2] содержали одинаковое количество значений, лишние значения не удалялись, а переносились в array[1]. Выравнивание значений подмассивов идет с array[0], я понимаю что можно перенести последнее значение array[0] на первую позицию array[1]. Не пойму как?

```
[array([118020., 118010., 118000., 117990.]),
 array([117980., 117970., 117960.]),
 array([117950., 117940., 117930.])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while len(lst[0]) != len(lst[2]):
      if len(lst[0]) < len(lst[2]):
           cache =lst[2].pop(-1)
           lst[1].insert(0, cache)
      else:
           cache =lst[0].pop(-1)
           lst[1].insert(0, cache)
```

Довольно просто, если знать методы списков.